# Using overlayfs on ext4 with casefold enabled?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, docker, overlay

My `dockerd` service was not working anymore and failed because it could not initialize the `overlay2` storage driver. I have a primary partition formatted with `ext4` that has the `casefold` option enabled. The involvement of `casefold` wasn't clear to me at the beginning.

Why is this happening and how can I get my docker setup to work again?

---

I initially noticed the issue when I tried to use `docker`. The `dockerd` log said the following:

```
level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: invalid argument" storage-driver=overlay2
level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver overlay2 failed: driver not supported"
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

While `dmesg` logged this:

```
overlayfs: filesystem on '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/check-overlayfs-support560506528/upper' not supported
```

---

Deleting / moving the `/var/lib/docker/` folder seemed to fix the issue at a first glance, but also comes with the downside of loosing all docker data. But after further investigation I stumbled upon these lines in the `dockerd` logs:

```
level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: invalid argument" storage-driver=overlay2
level=error msg="exec: \"fuse-overlayfs\": executable file not found in $PATH" storage-driver=fuse-overlayfs
level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=a61e2b4c9c graphdriver=vfs version=24.0.5
```

It seems that docker is now using `vfs` instead of `overlay2` as storage driver. `dmesg` also logs an error similar to the above on every restart of `dockerd`.

I could call it a day at that point in time, but neither do I want to live with the downsides of the `vfs` storage driver nor do I want to loose my previous docker data stored for usage with `overlay2`. So I dug deeper...

---

I found the [Kernel documentation on overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html#directories) and tried the example:

```bash
mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper,workdir=/work /merged
```

As expected it failed with the dmesg message:

```
overlayfs: filesystem on '/upper' not supported
```

Thinking back on what I had recently changed on my system setup only two things came to mind: Updates and enabling `casefold`. Enabling `casefold` is the more likely (and easily verifiable) option, so I wrote this simple script:

```bash
# create sparse file to create test filesystem (4 GiB)
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/image bs=1 count=1 seek=4294967295
# format with ext4, enabling casefold
mkfs.ext4 -O casefold /tmp/image
# mount image filesystem with loop device
mount -o loop /tmp/image /mnt
# create overlayfs directory structure in mounted test-filesystem
mkdir /mnt/lower /mnt/upper /mnt/work /mnt/merged
# mount overlay fs
mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/mnt/lower,upperdir=/mnt/upper,workdir=/mnt/work /mnt/merged
# clean up
umount /mnt/merged /tmp/image
rm /tmp/image
```

As I expected, it failes when run with `-O casefold` and works fine when `-O casefold` is omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a Linux Kernel bug submitted on 2022-09-10: [Overlay: filesystem not supported with ext4 and casefold](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216471)

So using overlayfs on a `ext4` with `casefold` is not supported yet. You might want to either move all data that needs `casefold` or the data in `/var/lib/docker/` to a separate partition.

---

The workaround that I am using works as follows:

1. Create a large sparse file for your docker data.
2. Format it with `ext4` and make sure that `casefold` is disabled.
3. Mount it as a loop device via your `/etc/fstab`.

The commands that I used to set this up look like this:

```bash
# stop the dockerd if it is running
systemctl stop docker.service
# create 256 GiB sparse file for docker data
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/docker.fs bs=1 count=1 seek=274877906943
# make sure only root can read it
chmod 600 /var/lib/docker.fs
# format it with ext4
mkfs.ext4 /var/lib/docker.fs
# move your docker data out of the way
mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.backup
# create the new docker directory
mkdir /var/lib/docker
chmod 810 /var/lib/docker
# create the fstab entry
echo '/var/lib/docker.fs /var/lib/docker auto loop 0 0' >>/etc/fstab
# reaload systemd (if you are using systemd)
systemctl daemon-reload
# mount it if it didn't already get auto-mounted by systemd
mount /var/lib/docker
# move all docker data to the new filesystem
mv /var/lib/docker.backup/* /var/lib/docker/
rmdir /var/lib/docker.backup
# start the dockerd
systemctl start docker.service
```

Make sure to choose a image size that is appropriately sized for your docker setup and hard drive size. You can check with `du -hs /var/lib/docker/` how much it is currently using to get a feel for how much you need.